# Maximum execution time exceeds due to session start?

Tags: zend-framework, time, zend-session, php

I am getting following error when I use Zend_Session::Start() in my bootstrap file.

```
Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in G:\wamp\library\Zend\Session.php on line 480
```

On line 480 of Zend\Session.php code is

```
$startedCleanly = session_start();
```

The browser keeps loading the page like forever due to it , its like infinite while loop .
Context

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

    protected $_config;
    protected $_acl;
    protected $_auth;

public function _initMyAutoloader()
{
    $autloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $autloader->pushAutoloader(new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array('basePath'=>APPLICATION_PATH . '/','namespace'=>'')));
    return $autloader ;

}

public function _initMyConfig()
{
    Zend_Session::start();
    $this->_config = new Zend_Config($this->getOptions());
    Zend_Registry::set('config',$this->_config);
    return $this->_config;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add some context for that line? (what comes before it?)

Comment: HM I had the same error once. It was because I was using Zend-Session with storing the information in a database. But I hadn't setup the database yet, to the point, where I started the session. Do you use the db-adapter for your session?

Comment: @Matt Ellen I added the context

Comment: @faileN no I am not using db adapter for session just the default adapter .

Comment: i never use `Zend_Session::start();` why do you need it? however obviously the problem is somewhere in your rest code, it throws the error somewhere in a random place it happens to be in this line, but it is not what caused it

Answer (score -2):

It's not because of session, but `max_execution_time`.

`max_execution_time` can be set in php.ini, so you can modify it:

```
max_execution_time = 60     ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
```